# What is the meaning of "stunt" here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

"They weren't meant to see each other, but a wicked **stunt** forces them into a impossible union-holy matrimony."

Stunt means an action displaying spectacular skill and daring, or prevent from growing or developing properly. but still i can't relate them and i feel strange.

Comment: Please cite the source, and if possible, the broader context.

Comment: Possibly used in the sense ‘to trick’.

Comment: There are also  usages such as in "...after you pull a stunt like that."...and a "political or advertising stunt."

Answer (score 2):

The word **stunt** used as a noun does mean a feat of daring and skill but, even in that sense, there is a connotation of the feat being done to impress or entertain. For instance someone climbing up a tower block to unfurl a political banner might be said to said to have **pulled a stunt** but a winchman on a rescue helicopter dropping to the deck of a small boat in heavy seas to pick up an injured person would not.

The [Lexico online dictionary](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/stunt) gives a secondary definition of **stunt** as a noun which is

> Something unusual done to attract attention

with the example

> ‘the story was spread as a publicity stunt to help sell books’

The [Longman dictionary](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/stunt) also gives a second definition of **stunt** as

> something that is done to attract people’s attention,
> especially in advertising or politics

with several examples including

> Todd flew over the city in a hot-air balloon as a publicity stunt
>
> A goofy stunt for February sweeps

and

> He also knew the value of goofy legal stunts

Now flying over a city in a hot air balloon could fit the skill and risk definition but it is by no means a exercise of an unusual level of skill (particularly if you have an experienced pilot doing the flying for you) but many advertising or political stunts require no physical skill, in fact even standing in a public place dressed in outrageous clothing, carrying placards and shouting slogans could be considered to be a **political stunt**. In that case no physical skill is required at all.

Similarly the staging of a more or less outrageous social media campaign could be called a **stunt** but it requires little physical skill and little or no danger or daring.

It is much more likely that the **stunt** referred to in the quoted passage was something along the lines of an advertising stunt than a feat of daring and skill.